# What type of object is 'whom' in this sentence?

Tags: pronouns, indirect-objects, direct-objects

In the sentence

> Whom is she calling?

what type of object is *whom*?

Is *whom* an indirect object because *she* is doing the calling to a person referred to as *whom*?

Comment: It's an object. In English, wh-pronouns are fronted, so the declarative form of this sentence (or the full answer to this) would be 'she is calling [John]'. 'Whom' refers to 'John', the object.

Answer (score 5):

"**Whom is she calling**?" has only one object and so it is the direct object.

Normally the **[ditransitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb)** verbs like *give, grant,* *tell* etc. take two objects (direct and indirect object).

The verb '**call**' is not a ditransitive verb except maybe in the idiomatic expression *['call names'](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/call+names)* meaning 'verbally abuse someone' (example: *He was calling me names because he disagreed with something I'd written*).

**Direct objects** normally answer the question *what?* and **indirect objects** answer the question *(to/for) whom?*

Examples:

*His father gave John enough money to buy a bike.* ((to)whom? - John = Indirect Object; what? - money = Direct Object)

Comment: Not a foolproof method. Some sentences with only one object have an indirect object instead of a direct one.

Comment: You can "call someone", or "call to someone". Call can be intransitive (most commonly in the sense of calling on the phone - "John is calling" - but also to shout or call out to someone).

Answer (score -1):

'Whom is she calling?' is incorrect. That should be 'Who is she calling ?', or 'To whom / with whom is she speaking?'
Whom is the residue of a *dative* case for nouns/pronouns, in older, more inflected versions of the english language

Comment: Although “whom” originates from a dative form, it has the function in modern English of both the dative and accusative cases (like “him”, “her” and other pronouns).

Comment: In American English, a question like "*Whom* did you promote?" would sound quite old-fashioned nowadays, and when **whom** is used here, it's typically the object of a preposition.  "With *whom* did you speak?"